# Access VBA Exporting

Tags: vba, export, ms-access-2007

I am trying to export a table to a `.txt` file to load into out Fulfillment software. I used

```
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "", "[Table Name]", "[Export Path Name]", False
```

and it worked great. However there is one small problem. The table has 10 product slots and the Fulfillment software only has 5. I would like to find a way useing `VBA` to export the customer info with the 5 products and check to see if they have a 6th one then if true export the same customer info again but this time with product fields `6-10`.

I couldn't find anything about exporting specific fields or a way to check for certain fields but I know it can be done.

Sorry if this seems vague. I tried to explain the best I could.

Thanks in advance for any help in this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating a query similar to the following, and then use `DoCmd.TransferText` to export it instead of exporting the table:

```
    SELECT CustomerID, Product1, Product2, Product3, Product4, Product5
    FROM [Table Name]
UNION ALL
    SELECT CustomerID, Product6, Product7, Product8, Product9, Product10
    FROM [Table Name]
    WHERE NOT
        (
            (Product6 IS NULL) AND (Product7 IS NULL) AND (Product8 IS NULL)
                AND (Product9 IS NULL) AND (Product10 IS NULL)
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

So if i get it your first goal is to export a table to a .txt?

In that case i would use a recordset like this:

```
Public Sub ExportToTxt(varTableYouWantToExport As String, pathFile As String)
    Dim filenumber
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rscurrent As Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String

    Open pathFile For Output As #filenumber
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & varTableYouWantToExport & ";"
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rscurrent = db.OpenRecordSet()

    rscurrent.MoveFirst

    While Not rscurrent.EOF
        Print #filenumber, vbCrLf & _
            rscurrent("Product_Id") & ";" _
            rscurrent("Product_Price") ";" _
            ...
        rscurrent.MoveNext
    Wend

    rscurrent.Close
    db.Close

    Close #filenumber
End Sub
```